# Pure CSS animation visibility with delay

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to implement some animation onLoad **without Javascript**. JS is easy, CSS is ... not.

I have a `div` which should be on `display: none;` and should be `display: block;` after 3 secondes. Lots of resources told me animate does not work with `display`, but should with `visibility` (which I use often in my transition).

Right know I have this terrible javascript function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".js_only").hide();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".js_only").show();
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

I tried some animation in CSS but no result ... nothing seems to work.

I have few animation in my page, but just struggling with the `display: none;` on animation.

```
@-moz-keyframes showEffect {
    0% { display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    100% { display: block; visibility: block;  }

}
@-webkit-keyframes showEffect {
    0% { display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    100% { display: block; visibility: block;  }

}
@keyframes showEffect {
    0% { display: none; visibility: hidden; }
    100% { display: block; visibility: block;  }
}

.css_only {
    -moz-animation-name: showEffect;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2.3s;

    -webkit-animation-name: showEffect;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2.3s;

    animation-name: showEffect;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 2.3s;
}
```

It is important as hidden, this element does not take space at all. [I created a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n51uvrnu/) to make quite tests.

My main concerne is SEO ... I don't think the JS option is really nice for that which is why I would like a pure CSS alternative. Also interested to test those animations and see where are those limits (Am I seeing one right now ?). Kinda having fun on such challenge.

Thanks for reading, hope someone has an answer.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) is not animatable. It won't work, and you shouldn't bother including it in keyframe animations.

[`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) is technically animatable, but in a round about way. You need to hold the property for as long as needed, then snap to the new value. `visibility` doesn't tween between keyframes, it just steps harshly.

```css
.ele {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  
  background-color: #ff6699;
  animation: 1s fadeIn;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ele:hover {
  background-color: #123;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ele"></div>
```

If you want to fade, you use `opacity`. If you include a delay, you'll need `visibility` as well, to stop the user from interacting with the element while it's not visible.

```css
.ele {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  
  background-color: #ff6699;
  animation: 1s fadeIn;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ele:hover {
  background-color: #123;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ele"></div>
```

Both examples use [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode), which can hold an element's visual state after an animation ends.

Comment: For visibility, instead of using keyframes, I think you're better off using a `transition` with a delay. For example: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

Comment: Note: don't forget to add animation-fill-mode: forwards property.

Comment: @Oka, what's the purpose of `visibility` if the `opacity` will disappear the element?

Comment: Combine this approach with a negative margin (for example margin-top: -200px) then at 100% set margin-top to initial desired value. When the element is min-height: 200px then you will have a smooth delay without the need of using JS tricks that are always a bit painful.

Answer (score 35):

Use **`animation-delay`**:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;

    animation: fadeIn 3s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpk1od6p/)

Comment: This was a pure and simple solution that was just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Question for you @Leo... Is there any way to make it so my div is compressed... as if it's not there and not taking up any px height on the screen, until the image fades in, then expand the area where the div is to display the content in the div (in my cas, an image)

Comment: if I understand well you can change the code with... div { width: 100px; height: 0px;... and... to { opacity: 1; height: 100px; }

Comment: That worked brilliantly!  Thanks for the tip! One last question. I love the fade in on the actual image in my div. What can I do to make it so when this compressed div is expanding to (e.g. height: 100px) to make it so it slowly expands (like the fade) to the full height?

Comment: did you see my last question about making the div slowly expand to display the previously opaque element to visible?

Comment: @jord8on If you want something to happen, and then something else to happen on another element, you should use two animations, the second one with an animation-delay of the duration of the first.

Answer (score 13):

You can play with `delay` prop of [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), just set `visibility:visible` after a **delay**, demo:

```css
@keyframes delayedShow {
  to {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.delayedShow{
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 0s linear 2.3s forwards delayedShow ;
}
```

```html
So, Where are you?

<div class="delayedShow">
  Hey, I'm here!
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't animate the `display` property. For a full list of what you can animate, try this [CSS animation list](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp) by w3 Schools.

If you want to retain it's visual position on the page, you should try animating either it's `height` (which will still affect the position of other elements), or `opacity` (how transparent it is). You could even try animating the `z-index`, which is the position on the z axis (depth), by putting an element over the top of it, and then rearranging what's on top. However, I'd suggest using `opacity`, as it retains the vertical space where the element is.

I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n51uvrnu/2/) to show an example.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

you can't animate every property,

[here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) a reference to which are the animatable properties

visibility is animatable while display isn't...

in your case you could also animate `opacity` or `height` depending of the kind of effect you want to render_

[fiddle with opacity animation](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/n51uvrnu/1/)

Comment: I'll upvote if you can make the fiddle work the other direction for the CSS element: from non visible to visible

Comment: visibility is the way to go for transitions, instead of opacity. works great.