# Jquery show CSS li after 12 second

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I got this button that I need to show after 12 second. I have no experience in css or javascrip

My Code

```css
.btn_waiting {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 12s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="listdm">
    <li><a href="./21.html" class="btn_waiting">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="./8.html">Back Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="./7.html">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: which button? I do not see a button in your HTML

Comment: @ochi read the question. It is there. `.btn_waiting`

Comment: @jai it is a class called `.btn_waiting` but it is a hyperlink (not a button)  - was I pedantic? (maybe) - was I incorrect? (technically... maybe) :)

Comment: look at: [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855985/pure-css-animation-visibility-with-delay) there is several solutions

Answer (score 5):

A pure CSS solution using animation frames.

```css
@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.btn_waiting {
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: appear 0s 12s 1 normal forwards ease-out
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="listdm">
    <li><a href="./21.html" class="btn btn_waiting">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="./8.html">Back Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="./7.html">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by adding the keyframe-animation effect and taking the animation timing to 12 seconds. Bellow code will work out for you.

```css
.btn_waiting {
  visibility: visible;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
   opacity:0;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="listdm">
    <li><a href="./21.html" class="btn_waiting">Next</a></li>
    <li><a href="./8.html">Back Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="./7.html">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: this shows the link almost immediately (not after 12s) - the transition may take 12s but the link is visible long before that

Comment: add to css: `99%{opacity:0}`

Comment: Yes, you can use `opacity` if you want a fading effect, but in the OP's case, animating the `visibility` will do.