# JavaScript recursive setTimeout() not working correctly after few hours

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, intervals

In my web application I use recursive setTimeout() to call a function every second (see below).

```
function test() {
    console.log('test');
    setTimeout(test, 1000);
}

test();
```

It is working good, but after around 6 hours, it calls the test() function only every 3 seconds or so. (setInterval() has the same problem)

The program needs to run 24h a day and has to update every second. Any ideas how to fix this problem.

Here is the full code:

```
function updateDateTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    
    /* Date */
    var woy = moment(now).format('W');
    var dow = now.getDay();
    var d = now.getDate();
    var m = now.getMonth();
    var y = now.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('date_day').innerHTML = daysOfWeek[dow];
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = d + ". " + monthsOfYear[m] + " " + y;
    document.getElementById('date_week').innerHTML = "KW " + woy;

    /* Time */
    var h = now.getHours();
    var m = now.getMinutes();
    var s = now.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    
    /*if(odd)*/
        $("#time_colon").css('visibility', 'visible');
    /*else
        $("#time_colon").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    odd = !odd;*/
    
    document.getElementById('time_h').innerHTML = h;
    document.getElementById('time_m').innerHTML = m;
    document.getElementById('time_s').innerHTML = s;
    
    /* Clock */
    drawClock(now);
    
    setTimeout(updateDateTime, 1000 - moment().milliseconds() + 50);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
  return i;
}
```

There are also some other functions that should update every 15 minutes with Ajax requets like that:

```
function updateNews() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "newsapi";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('news').innerHTML = '';
            var news = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for(e in news){
                data = news[e];
                document.getElementById('news').innerHTML += '<span class="mx-3">'+data.title+'</span>';
                if(e < news.length) {
                    document.getElementById('news').innerHTML += ' &middot; ';
                }
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    
    setTimeout(updateNews, 1800*1000);
}
```

I also use code to disable screen sleep mode for chrome browser:

```
if ('wakeLock' in navigator) {
    // Screen Wake Lock API supported 
    // The wake lock sentinel.
    let wakeLock = null;
    
    // Function that attempts to request a screen wake lock.
    const requestWakeLock = async () => {
        try {
            wakeLock = await navigator.wakeLock.request();
            wakeLock.addEventListener('release', () => {
                console.log('Screen Wake Lock released:', wakeLock.released);
            });
            console.log('Screen Wake Lock released:', wakeLock.released);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`${err.name}, ${err.message}`);
        }
    };
    
    // Request a screen wake lock…
    requestWakeLock();
}
```

If you need more information, just write a comment.

**NEW UPDATE:**
This morning I saw that the news data was not updated because of a crash of my server, but the time was still correct after 12 hours or so. But 4 hours later, after I restarted my server and the clock, the time had 2 seconds offset. So I guess that the offset of the setTimeout depends on the Ajax requests in other timeouts.

Here is a list of my results:

| timeout value                      | device | offset                                      | browser |
| 1000 - moment().milliseconds() + 50 | raspi  | 2 seconds after around 4-6 hours            | chrome & firefox |
| 1000 - moment().milliseconds() + 50 | raspi  | no offset but without working ajax requests | chrome |
| 1000 | raspi  | around 2 seconds after around 4-6 hours            | chrome & firefox |
| 500 | raspi  | around 2 seconds after around 4-6 hours            | chrome & firefox |

Comment: Sounds like you've overflowed the stack, since the first function call still hasn't finished by the time you run into problems after continuing to issue function calls for another 6 hours. What does your code utilizing setInterval look like? It's not also recursive, is it?

Comment: If the page isn't focused then the browser throttles JavaScript in the page to run timeouts less frequently. You have no control over this behavior.

Comment: @enhzflep `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` don't push frames onto a stack, that's not the issue.

Comment: This example degrades over time? Or just your code? I have built dashboard app that rely on this sort of code and they run for months at a time between updates.

Comment: I think this example is a bit too simplified, what are you actually doing inside that function in your application?

Comment: The page is always focussed and I tried already with ``setInterval()``, but that leads to the same problem. I added the code of the update function to my question.

Comment: @Adrian Brand Can you tell me which browser you use for your dashboard app?

Comment: Could you try with a smaller interval to see if it happens sooner?  (sorry I can't spend 6hrs to try to repro) Also, does this happen only in one browser or multiple? When it happens, does it still happen after you interact with the page? Are other calls to setTimeout affected? (e.g try from the console to call an other function in a timeout) You could try to limit this issue by using a [drift correction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61810342/3702797) in your loop, but setInterval should have one already in Chrome...

Comment: Oh and when it happens, could you try to check the performance and memory tabs of your dev-tools. Maybe it's just that you have some memory leak or an other code running that does add a very small overhead, that ends up being a big one.

Comment: I tested the program in Chromium and Firefox, both got the same issue and are running on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu on it. I will also try it on my laptop and I will change the timeout to 500ms. I had that already and it was the same issue. But I guess that It last longer with async prepended to the function.

Comment: I tried already to call ``setTimeout()`` manually from console after I saw the offset of the other timeouts. The result was around 5 seconds instead of 2 seconds.

Comment: For the 1 second interval I used ``1000 - moment().milliseconds() + 50`` in ``setTimeout()``. I thought this is a kind of drift correction.

Comment: If even outside setTimeouts are affected this would point toward a memory or cpu leak (moreover on a raspi). Check the dev-tools for both performances and memory and see what shouldn't be that big normally.

Comment: The values on the memory and performance tab of chrome are looking all normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

You just need to call the setTimeout() events when the Ajax request is completed.