# CSS animation-iteration-count not working properly

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to make a loading spinner out of fractions.
- What's expected: Say, I have fraction_1 with 0 delay, it stays in place for 6s, while the other 5 appear every second. At the 6s mark fraction_1 disappears. The same is happening to each other fragment, they're kept in sync with a 1s delay. And then it starts over.
- What's happening: Iteration breaks down all the animations, fragments slowly become visible and just stay there, without disappearing, or don't appear/disappear at all. Current version plays once and then stops, even though iteration is specified. Changing it from int to infinite doesn't work.
 I've tried most of the visibility/keyframe step combinations
   (display:none/block isn't affecting anything), like making it visible
   by default and disappearing, starting with hidden and then drawing
   each piece to visible from 0 to 100, from 0 to 50 to 100... it just
   won't work.

Code in question:

```css
.holder{
  width:210px;
  height:210px;
}

.cover{
  margin-left:16px;
  margin-top:18px;
  position:absolute;
  width:169px;
  height:169px;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 12px white;
}

.fraction_1, .fraction_2, .fraction_3, .fraction_4, .fraction_5, .fraction_6{
  visibility:hidden;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:52px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  position: absolute;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-left:50px solid transparent;
  border-right:50px solid transparent;
  border-top:88px solid #ED553B;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform-origin:bottom center;
}
.fraction_1{
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 0s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_2{
  transform:rotate(60deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 1s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_3{
  transform:rotate(120deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 2s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_4{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 3s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_5{
  transform:rotate(-120deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 4s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_6{
  transform:rotate(-60deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 5s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}

@keyframes fractioned{
  0%{ 
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  50%{
    visibility:visible;
  }
  100%{
    visibility:hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="fraction_1"></div>
  <div class="fraction_2"></div>
  <div class="fraction_3"></div>
  <div class="fraction_4"></div>
  <div class="fraction_5"></div>
  <div class="fraction_6"></div>
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

- Another thing - I don't know how to properly name this version. Yes, it's a loading spinner, but that's broad and brings up a lot of unwanted results. Adding 'Circle pie' and 'fractions/fragments' didn't help with the search. Perhaps, if I knew the exact type, I could find a semi-working solution to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from the iteration count which **does** work. You can see it in the snippet below, where I added an animation for the color as well and it's played 5 times.

```css
.holder{
  width:210px;
  height:210px;
}

.cover{
  margin-left:16px;
  margin-top:18px;
  position:absolute;
  width:169px;
  height:169px;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 12px white;
}

.fraction_1, .fraction_2, .fraction_3, .fraction_4, .fraction_5, .fraction_6{
  visibility:hidden;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:52px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  position: absolute;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-left:50px solid transparent;
  border-right:50px solid transparent;
  border-top:88px solid #ED553B;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform-origin:bottom center;
}
.fraction_1{
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 0s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_2{
  transform:rotate(60deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 1s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_3{
  transform:rotate(120deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 2s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_4{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 3s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_5{
  transform:rotate(-120deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 4s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
}
.fraction_6{
  transform:rotate(-60deg);
  animation:fractioned 1s ease 5s;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fractioned{
  0%{ 
    visibility:hidden;
    border-top:88px solid #ED553B;
  }
  50%{
    visibility:visible;
    border-top:88px solid #11113B;
  }
  100%{
    visibility:hidden;
    border-top:88px solid #ED2222;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="fraction_1"></div>
  <div class="fraction_2"></div>
  <div class="fraction_3"></div>
  <div class="fraction_4"></div>
  <div class="fraction_5"></div>
  <div class="fraction_6"></div>
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

It's the `visibility`property that fools you **and** your solution to delay the animation. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30856455/6691953) provides some insight:

> visibility is technically animatable, but in a round about way. You need to hold the property for as long as needed, then snap to the new value. visibility doesn't tween between keyframes, it just steps harshly.

So, the key is to redefine your animation by changing the last key-frame from `100%` to `51%`. Additionally, I removed the `ease` of your animation (which by the way doesn't take an argument) and replaced it with a delay to time the animation. Furthermore, I increased the whole animation duration to comply with your demand of 1s steps of the animation.

```css
.holder {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
}

.cover {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 169px;
  height: 169px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px white;
}

.fraction_1,
.fraction_2,
.fraction_3,
.fraction_4,
.fraction_5,
.fraction_6 {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 52px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 88px solid #ED553B;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  animation: fractioned 12s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.fraction_1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.fraction_2 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.fraction_3 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.fraction_4 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.fraction_5 {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.fraction_6 {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@keyframes fractioned {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  51% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="fraction_1"></div>
  <div class="fraction_2"></div>
  <div class="fraction_3"></div>
  <div class="fraction_4"></div>
  <div class="fraction_5"></div>
  <div class="fraction_6"></div>
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Guess I blamed the wrong property. Tried 0-99%-100% before, suspecting there's a momentarily change taking place, but it didn't cut it. Thank you for the thorough explanation and a working example!