# I want my <p> tag to display after 5s in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a heading `<h1>I am Heading</h1>` with animation properties and I want to display my `<p>I am Paragraph</p>`  to display after heading fully loaded

Comment: In pure CSS, use animation keyframes or transitions to do this, look up either to see how that would be done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure CSS animation visibility with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855985/pure-css-animation-visibility-with-delay)

Answer (score 0):

Attach an [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event listener to the `h1` that shows the paragraph element in 5000 milliseconds with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```js
const heading = document.querySelector('h1');
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
heading.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  console.log('showing paragraph in 5 seconds')
  setTimeout(() => {
    paragraph.style.display = "block"
  }, 5000)
})
```

```css
h1 {
  animation: fadeIn 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>I am Heading</h1>

<p>I am Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `setTimeout()` method can execute a piece of code after a certain amount of time has passed.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p id="para">Hey this is saruque</p>
    <style>
        @keyframes show {
            from{
                opacity: 0;
            }
            to{
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        h1{
            animation: show 5s forwards;
        }

        #para{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(params) {
                document.getElementById('para').style.visibility = 'visible'
            }, 5200);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a delay to your animation:

```
p {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: .4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.