# CSS delayed visibility transition doesn't trigger JavaScript transitionend event for visibility?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm using the technique for delaying `visibility` transition, combined with `opacity`. This is working nice:

```html
<body>
  <button>run</button>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

```css
.box {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /* property name | duration | easing function | delay */
  transition: visibility 0s ease-in-out 3s,
              opacity 3s ease-in-out;
}

.box.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

**The problem** happens when I listen to the `transitionend` event. This should log both `visibility` and `opacity` properties, but instead only the `opacity` is logged ([pen here](https://codepen.io/gremo/pen/VwQOZKY)):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

// When class "show" is added, only "opacity" is logged
// When class "show" is removed, both "opacity" and "visibility" are logged
box.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
  console.log(e.propertyName);
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  box.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

**Why I need to listen to `transitioned`?** with this event I'am checking the number of transition properties (`totalProperties`); when all properties are transitioned (tracking with a `counter`), I know that element actually finished all its transitions:

```
const totalProperties = window.getComputedStyle(element)['transition-property'].split(',').length;
let counter = 0;

const callback = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();

  if (++counter === totalProperties) {
    counter = 0;
    box.removeEventListener('transitionend', callback);

    console.log('All properties transitioned.');
  }
};

box.addEventListener('transitionend', callback);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event:

> If there is no transition delay or duration, if both are 0s or neither is declared, there is no transition, and none of the transition events are fired.

```
transition: visibility 0s ease-in-out 3s
```

Your transition-duration for visibility is `0s` here.

Make that `.0001s`, and you'll see the transitionend event for visibility fire as well.

Comment: Thanks, could be, but it doesn't explain why, when you hide the box (second click on the button) logs also `visibility` (`transition-duration` is still `0s` for that property).

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30856455/943435

Comment: _"transition-duration is still 0s for that property"_ - but `transition-delay` isn't. As long as `.box.show` applies, you have `transition-delay: 0s` - which sets the delay to 0 for both opacity & visibility, and combined with the duration of 0 for `visibility`, you got _both_ as 0 for visibility. But when you remove the `show` class, then the delay of  `3s` for `visibility` applies again.

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear to me. When `.show` doesn't apply, `visibility` has `0s` duration and `3s` delay. So event doesn't fire, because duration is `0s`. I would say the same when `.show` is removed: duration is still `0s` and delay `3s`. To summarize, `visibility` **never get a duration** so the event should never be fired. What I'm missing here?

Comment: _"When .show doesn't apply, visibility has 0s duration and 3s delay. So event doesn't fire, because duration is 0s. "_ - no, the event doesn't fire, because _both_ are 0. We are talking about the case where you just _added_ the `show` class to the element here - and that explicitly applies `transition-delay: 0s`, so for visibility, you have _both_ duration & delay with value 0 now. Look at the _calculated_ values for the `transition` property on the element, in both cases.

Comment: Now i undertsand, thanks a lot @CBroe